# Magento current category? Which one is better?

Tags: magento

Which is better to use for getting current category in custom created category/product listing page?

`1. Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();`

`2. Mage::registry('current_category');`

Which is require much time to execute?? And has higher impact on performance?

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is Much faster than Option 1. because it directly return current category from registry.

If you check the `getCurrentCategory` function in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer.php` Model, you will find this function do the same. but it also have the condition to check if current category not set then returns root category. Using option 1 we reduce the chances for errors.